# How is NVIDIA Prime Render Offloading configured in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, nvidia-optimus, xserver

Yesterday I installed Kubuntu 20.04 from scratch on a Lenovo Thinkpad T490 laptop with a GeForce MX250 discrete graphics adapter.

Prime render offloading fails with:

```
$ __NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia glxgears
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  152 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  25
  Current serial number in output stream:  26
```

This was working perfectly in 19.10 on the same machine, using xserver-xorg-core version 2:1.20.5+git20191008-0ubuntu1.

How is Prime render offloading supposed to work in Ubuntu 20.04?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the default graphics configuration in stock Ubuntu 20.04 does not properly support PRIME render offloading, but adding the "Proprietary GPU Drivers" ppa solves everything.

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt dist-upgrade
$ shutdown -r now
```

And everything works perfect on reboot.

Comment: I went through your steps but it has not solved the problem for me; I still get the error message "PRIME: is it supported? no" when I try to run `nvidia-settings`. I have added the repository and installed the most recent version (nvidia-driver-440) which is the recommended driver. Do you have any other suggestions on how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: @JJGabe, I'm afraid not. Both times I've had to deal with this issue, it came down to package sources (like installing the patched xsever in 19.10), and I don't really understand the difference between the versions available in the 20.04 repos and the graphics-drivers ppa. As far as I know, all of them should support on-demand offloading, so I assume it's a config issue, but that as far as I'd there to comment. Sorry :(

Comment: Oh well, thanks for responding. This has been an ongoing struggle for me since 16.04. I don't do much gaming or 3D rendering anyway so it's not a big deal but it just seems a waste to leave an nvidia card dormant while using a built in Intel graphics card haha.

Comment: Same for me : it don't work with 450 nvidia driver and ubuntu 20.04 Any idea ?

Comment: @Oli, honestly, no idea. I just reinstalled 20.04 from scratch on this machine (a Lenovo Thinkpad T490), and on-demand PRIME render offloading works out of the box using nvidia-driver-440. I assume the issue has something to do with installation options etc, but as I said above, every time I've had to deal with this issue, I solved it by using a ppa or, most recently, by installing everything from scratch. I'd love to share my conf for you to look for the difference, but I wouldn't even know where to begin looking for the relevant files. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I've done a new installation to make everything clean and now it works !
But is this only "manual" to take the nvidia GPU ? Nothing automatic as said here for the 435 driver ? On the sreenshot you can see "Nvidia On-Demand". I don't have this option on my 450 driver.
https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/08/nvidia-43517-linux-beta-driver-adds.html

Comment: @Oli, "On-demand" render offloading means that you can run applications on one or the other GPU _without restarting X_, by exporting the value of some variables in your environment (https://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/435.17/README/primerenderoffload.html). If your nvidia-settings is not showing the middle option, but only "Intel" or "NVIDIA", then render offloading is not properly configured in your setup, and you will need to manually switch between GPUs and restart X. But I don't know why: 20.04 should support it out of the box. Sorry :(

Comment: Hi I can run applications on my iGPU (default) and eGPU whith the prefix `__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __VK_LAYER_NV_optimus=NVIDIA_only __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia`. It works fine.
I understood that the switch was automatic in thne "On Demand" mode, but as you said it seems that I am wrong.
In nvidia-settings I have absolutly no "PRIME Profiles" entry. Do you have one with the 450 driver ? Or did this disappear since 435 version and with the 450 update ?
This windows is missing : https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/08/nvidia-43517-linux-beta-driver-adds.html

Comment: Another thing, `nvidia-settings` says `PRIME: No offloading required. Abort PRIME: is it supported? no` but as said below it works with the prefix. I can see it on power consumption with nvidia-smi.

Comment: @Oli, ok that's weird. As far as I know: 1) nvidia settings should have a PRIME profiles entry, 2) if offloading is supported and properly configured, there should be an "On Demand" profile and 3) "On demand" _does not_ mean it will automatically decide on which GPU to run, you still need those env vars present; it just means that you won't need to restart X to switch from one GPU to another. So I would say there is some problem with your setup. Is nvidia-settings showing all options? are you sure you have the correct version for your nvidia driver? Also: I'm not on 450, I'm on 440, no issues.

Comment: OK I undestand : on demand is not automatic as in windows. In manual mode with the prefixe above it works. It seems only that there is little bug in the display of nvidia settings but it doesn't matter for working normaly "on demand".

Comment: Thanks this worked for me with Ubuntu 20.04 3060Ti SteamVR

Comment: I don't know what actually fixes this, I did this and then the vulkan comment https://github.com/ValveSoftware/SteamVR-for-Linux/issues/355#issuecomment-635919607 also working for 1050ti now

Answer (score 0):

I just got it working! :-)

Using the latest NVidia driver 455 from the PPA, running on Ubuntu Mate 20.04.1  Running in NVidia Hybrid (On-Demand) mode.

It uses Intel video for normal desktop stuff, and NVidia works when using the offload command

```
__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME="nvidia" __VK_LAYER_NV_optimus="NVIDIA_only" %command%  
like __NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME="nvidia" __VK_LAYER_NV_optimus="NVIDIA_only" glxgears
```

Go to `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/` and make a new conf file  (I called mine `20-intel.conf` but it doesn't matter) and used these contents:

```
Section "Module"
    Load "dri3"
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "layout"
    Screen 0 "intel"
    Screen 1 "nvidia"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "intel"
    Driver "intel"
    BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
    Option      "DRI"   "3"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "intel"
    Device "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Driver "nvidia"
    BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
    Option "ConstrainCursor" "off"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Device "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "on"
    Option "IgnoreDisplayDevices" "CRT"
EndSection
```

Comment: I just discovered that the BusID section is irrelevant - solution works without the PCI bus info