# AMD and NVIDIA GPUs together on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: nvidia, graphics, xorg, amd-graphics, 20.04

I recently got AMD Radeon RX 5700 XT card and I already had a GeForce RTX 2070 as my main GPU for sometime now.
I was trying to run them together and managed to do that on manjaro after installing the AMD card as the main one and running applications on the NVIDA card with prime-run when needed, now I'm trying to move back to Ubuntu and I can't get the same configuration running.

1. prime-run doesn't work at all even after installing `nvidia-prime`
2. Running anything with env vars `__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=2 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia` doesn't work

```
root@my-pc:~#__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=2 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia glxinfo | grep OpenGL
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  152 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  39
  Current serial number in output stream:  40
```

I installed the proprietary drivers for both cards tried the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1233606/1076325) and nothing seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was fixed by removing nvidia drivers and reinstalling them.

Answer (score 5):

It's not really the answer, but if it helps.

I have both AMD and Nvidia on a laptop
I force Nvidia with instruction from https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/i-cant-enable-nvidia-gpu-with-nvidia-prime/69899/4

In this file  `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia.conf`
I put:

> Option   "PrimaryGPU" "true"

And reboot

Comment: what about xorg.conf, may I put that into device section?

Comment: For me the `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/11-nvidia-prime.conf` contains the `PrimaryGPU` setting already (search for `prime-select`). Also the `xorg.conf` in `/etc/X11` should take precedence.

Answer (score 3):

Steps to install Ubuntu 20 with Nvidia + AMD

1. Install [Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS (Focal Fossa) server](https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04/ubuntu-20.04.2-live-server-amd64.iso)
2. Once started

   ```
   apt-get update && time apt-get dist-upgrade
   ```
3. Reboot and then install AMD drivers

   ```
   wget --referer https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux-20-45 https://drivers.amd.com/drivers/ linux / amdgpu-pro-20.45-1188099-ubuntu-20.04.tar.xz
   tar xJf amdgpu-pro-20.45-1188099-ubuntu-20.04.tar.xz </code>
   cd amdgpu-pro-20.45-1188099-ubuntu-20.04
   sudo ./amdgpu-pro-install --opencl=legacy,pal --headless --no-dkms
   ```
4. Restart and install Nvidia drivers

   ```
   ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
   # Note: check with nvidia-smi
   # If it has not been installed correctly then execute:
   sudo apt install nvidia-driver-455
   ```
5. Reboot and install `clinfo`

   ```
   apt install clinfo
   ```

   run `clinfo` to check that both cards have been detected