# Force Xorg to use AMD GPU over Nvidia GPU

Tags: nvidia, xorg, amd-graphics, amdgpu, xorg.conf

So I have an Nvidia GPU in my workstation that I mostly use for compute tasks (CUDA). This however causes display freezes when the GPU is under heavy load. My idea is to get a secondary GPU to route my displays (*). Since I had an old HD6950 lying around, I was able to run some initial tests.

- Both the Nvidia/AMD card are able to  drive my monitors individually, when no other card is present
- When both cards are in the system, for some reason the Nvidia card takes precedence over the AMD card. While I can use the AMD card in BIOS and GRUB, as soon as I decrypt the hard drive the system automatically switches to the Nvidia card.

**Questions:**

1. How can one force Xorg to use the AMD GPU to power the monitors?**
2. Would it be a solution to only install "headless" Nvidia drivers?

**Note:**

- The AMD card worked without any additional drivers, though, I tried installing the `amdgpu` drivers but this seemingly changed nothing.
- Getting a second Nvidia card seems suboptimal since (A) they are more expensive (B) I didn't find a single one with more than 4 digital outputs, and if I go through this hassle anyway I could just go all the way.
- Related? [AMD and NVIDIA GPUs together on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1234274/amd-and-nvidia-gpus-together-on-ubuntu-20-04)

---

**Update** Ok so funnily, it works after I deleted my `xorg.conf` file, which referenced the nvidia-driver. I tried replacing it with `amdgpu` but that didn't work. It worked after purging `amdgpu` and using ?default? VGA drivers? It seems to work like intended, but surely that is not the correct way to set it up. I tried `X -configure` in recovery mode to create a new config, but the generated one didn't work.

---

(*) My target setup is the following: get a [Sapphire GPRO 6200](https://www.sapphiretech.com/en/commercial/gpro-6200-4g-gddr5-pci-e-eyefinity-6-edition) or equivalent as the display card. Then, for airflow reasons, my idea is to slot this card vertically via a riser cable in the last PCIex16 slot.

Comment: You may check the GPU assignments with xrandr --listproviders and switch things on a per program basis with environment variables : __NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia <progtorun>

Answer (score 2):

1. Check if `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` already exists

   - If not, create it via `Xorg -Configure` (requires no active X session):

     - Drop to TTY session (e.g. `ctrl+alt+F3`)
     - Stop gnome desktop manager  `service gdm stop`
     - `Xorg -configure`
     - `sudo cp /home/$USER/xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf`
   - If it does, make a backup `sudo cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.bak`
2. Uncomment Nvidia-GPU related `Decive` section in the `xorg.conf`.
3. Reboot

If the computer doesn't want to boot anymore, go into recovery mode and either delete `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` or roll out the backup.

Example `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`

```ini
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "X.org Configured"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
    Screen      2  "Screen2" RightOf "Screen1"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
EndSection

Section "Files"
    ModulePath   "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi"
    FontPath     "built-ins"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load  "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Keyboard0"
    Driver      "kbd"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Mouse0"
    Driver      "mouse"
    Option      "Protocol" "auto"
    Option      "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
    Option      "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor0"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor1"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor2"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: <i>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>: "True"/"False",
        ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz",
        ### <percent>: "<f>%"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "Accel"                 # [<bool>]
        #Option     "SWcursor"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "EnablePageFlip"        # [<bool>]
        #Option     "SubPixelOrder"         # [<str>]
        #Option     "ZaphodHeads"           # <str>
        #Option     "AccelMethod"           # <str>
        #Option     "DRI3"                  # [<bool>]
        #Option     "DRI"                   # <i>
        #Option     "ShadowPrimary"         # [<bool>]
        #Option     "TearFree"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "DeleteUnusedDP12Displays"  # [<bool>]
        #Option     "VariableRefresh"       # [<bool>]
        #Option     "AsyncFlipSecondaries"  # [<bool>]
    Identifier  "Card0"
    Driver      "amdgpu"
    BusID       "PCI:36:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: <i>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>: "True"/"False",
        ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz",
        ### <percent>: "<f>%"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "Accel"                 # [<bool>]
        #Option     "SWcursor"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "EnablePageFlip"        # [<bool>]
        #Option     "SubPixelOrder"         # [<str>]
        #Option     "ZaphodHeads"           # <str>
        #Option     "AccelMethod"           # <str>
        #Option     "DRI3"                  # [<bool>]
        #Option     "DRI"                   # <i>
        #Option     "ShadowPrimary"         # [<bool>]
        #Option     "TearFree"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "DeleteUnusedDP12Displays"  # [<bool>]
        #Option     "VariableRefresh"       # [<bool>]
        #Option     "AsyncFlipSecondaries"  # [<bool>]
    Identifier  "Card1"
    Driver      "amdgpu"
    BusID       "PCI:36:0:1"
EndSection

#Section "Device"
        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: <i>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>: "True"/"False",
        ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz",
        ### <percent>: "<f>%"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "SWcursor"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "HWcursor"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "NoAccel"               # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ShadowFB"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "VideoKey"              # <i>
        #Option     "WrappedFB"             # [<bool>]
        #Option     "GLXVBlank"             # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ZaphodHeads"           # <str>
        #Option     "PageFlip"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "SwapLimit"             # <i>
        #Option     "AsyncUTSDFS"           # [<bool>]
        #Option     "AccelMethod"           # <str>
        #Option     "DRI"                   # <i>
#   Identifier  "Card2"
#   Driver      "nouveau"
#   BusID       "PCI:45:0:0"
#EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    Device     "Card0"
    Monitor    "Monitor0"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     1
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     4
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     8
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     15
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     16
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen1"
    Device     "Card1"
    Monitor    "Monitor1"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     1
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     4
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     8
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     15
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     16
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen2"
    Device     "Card2"
    Monitor    "Monitor2"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     1
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     4
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     8
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     15
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     16
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Comment: This helped me with passing my first GPU to a VM. I could disable the first GPU, but could not set the Gnome to use the second GPU. With this configuration, I've succeeded passing my first GPU to a VM and use my second GPU for the host. [Link to my question on Unix&Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/735172/gnome-hangs-with-vfio-gpu-passthrough)